# Press multiple TouchableOpacity elements on react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm developing an application that must play multiple sound. Well, I'm using react-native-sound library. It's awesome but, my sounds must be played when the user press TouchableOpacity element. However, when I'm testing on my Android device, I can play sounds when I'm pressing a button, good, but when I want press two buttons together, nothing append or only one sound was played.

An example of my code :

```
export default class PayerButton extends Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={ this.playTheSound(this.props.mySound) }
            >
                <Text>Play this sound</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }


    playTheSound() { ... }


}
```

In my App component, I have two elements PlayerButton. I want press element together and they play there sound together for example.

Thank you for your help :)

Enjoy.

Comment: The issue [here](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/374) seems to suggest it may be an issue with the underlying library you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can play multiple sound. I just can't press two button together. I had created different variable for each sound and with a switch, I'm playing the sound. Sound work. But I don't know how press two buttons together for example

Comment: @TaharChibane did you ever find a solution for pressing multiple TouchableOpacity buttons at once?